# Simplify multiple If-Else statement

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is any way to simplify the following if-self code:

```
if(a == null)
{
  variant = 1;
} else if (a == b)
{
  variant = 5;
} else if (a == c && a != d)
{
  variant = 6
} else if ....
```

I ready don't want to use too much if else in my code but `variant` needs to be assigned to a different value depends on `a`.

Thanks.

Comment: Simplify; no. Complexify so you get rid of the slightly smelly `if....else`; yes of course.

Comment: https://seanbarry.dev/posts/switch-true-pattern

Comment: You can try to find common variants. Like if `a == c` is used in multiple places then you can put a single branch for those.

Comment: @WiktorZychla switch(true) actually sounds promising. Why I never think of this before. Thank you. I will try it :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Won't work with C#, which requires constant `case` expressions.

Comment: @Heinzi c# has had case expressions for about 3 versions now

Comment: @Jamiec: We might be talking about different things. My point is that `switch (true) { case (a == b) ...` won't work in C#. If I'm wrong here, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Should your first expression be a == null? Otherwise, your expression tree doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Heinzi you're sort of not wrong except the assertion that `requires constant case expressions` hasnt been the case (pun! lolz) for a while now

Comment: @Jamiec: I see your point. I know that we have pattern matching now, but if you use a simple expression (rather than pattern matching and the `when` clause), it needs to be constant.

Comment: @j2associates yes. My bad. Edited :)

Comment: @Heinzi it should be `switch (true) { case true when a == b: ...}`

Comment: @Hector: Indeed, that would work. Whether it's more readable is probably a matter of taste...

Comment: @Heinzi: it won't but somehow I'd swear I saw JavaScript tag here.

Answer (score 3):

In these situations I prefer chained ternary operations:

```
variant = 
      a == null ? 1
    : a == b ? 5
    : a == c && a != d ? 6
    : variant; // or whatever final default value you want
```

Comment: multiple nested ternary operators is an _awful_ idea. hard to read, hard to fix bugs, hard to enhance.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I don't find long chains of ternarys very readable

Comment: I think this one is too hard to read and not clear especially if there are a lot of other conditions.

Comment: Hmm, I like them, so hearing that others don't is good feedback.  I'll probably just keep the answer alive just to keep it as a record.  Thanks to all of you.

Comment: It's probably down to personal preference, I know that many people don't like nested ternaries. I think your solution is fine and, under the right circumstances (and correctly indented), nested ternaries *can* be quite readable.

Comment: @VitaliySmolyakov, yes, tough I had to edit to delete that since the OP changed the first condition on edit.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with a long sequence of `if - else if` statements.

Since you asked for an alternative: If you extract that code into a separate method, you can use `return` statements and regular `if`s instead. It also gets rid of the redundant `variant = ...` assignment, documents your code and keeps your methods short.

```
int DetermineVariant(int? a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a == null)
        return 1;

    if (a == b)
        return 5;

    if (a == c && a != d)
        return 6;

    // more conditions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be criticized, but if you change a little bit the appearance of your code maybe it doesn't look too "long".

```cs
   if(a == null) variant = 1;
   else if (a == b) variant = 5;
   else if (a == c && a != d) variant = 6;
   else if ....
```

And you don't get your code more difficult to read. Even [pwilcox version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68117883/10109389)  (which is very nice, btw), is more complicated to read than a simple if-else.